# Selenium: How to choose another child element under the same parent element (C#)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, element

I have a question on selecting child element within a parent element while locator chose another child element.

I have following page:

```
<tbody class="x-list-container"> <tr class="first-row"> <div class="x-supplier-dropdown">   <div>
    <div id="s2id_autogen75" class="select2-container x-input select2-container-active select2-dropdown-open" style="width: 100%;">
      <a class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1"> 
        <span class="select2-chosen">Yes</span>
        <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close">
        </abbr> 
      </a>
      <input id="s2id_autogen76" class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" disabled="disabled" type="text" />
    </div>
    <input class="x-input select2-offscreen" tabindex="-1" name="Supplier" type="text" />   
</div> 
</div> 
<p>   
<a class="btn btn-link btn-copy-field x-copy-to-all" data-field="Supplier">Copy to all</a>  
</p>
```

I have a number of similar elements with different Names (the Name is the unique part). Thus I'm searching for specific element by "Name" Contains, using following method (where 'fieldName' == 'Supplier' in current example):

```
element = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".x-list-container [name*='" + fieldName + "']"))[index];
element2 = element.FindElements(By.ClassName("select2-chosen")).First();
```

But it does not find anything for 'element2'.
How can I search for the child element by the Name Contains, and get the whole parent element.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only element with **.x-list-container** class in your html is the root tbody element and it doesn't have a name attribute to it .  Consider using   **By.CssSelector("tbody.x-list-container")** for finding the tbody element. **".x-list-container [name*='Supplier']"** won't match anything in above html.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have provided to identify the element with text e.g. **Supplier** and then with reference to this node to find the `<span>` node with some text e.g **Yes** you can use the following line of code :

```
element = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@class='x-input select2-offscreen' and contains(@name,'" + fieldName + "')]//preceding::div[1]/a/span[@class='select2-chosen']"));
```

Comment: Thanks DebanjanB. Unfortunately, this does not work. I'm getting following error: "OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'Unable to locate element: //input[@class='x-input select2-offscreen' and contains(@name,'Supplier')]//preceding::div[1]/a/span[@class='select2-chosen']'
"